# Which are the option to promote my app game in different app stores?

Tags: marketing, publishing, appstore

We've few Android App projects at the moment anmd we're looking for a way to publish our appGames in differents AppStores around the globe.

Do someone know a fast way to submit or some management tools for App publishers?

Thanks